# salary of android developer

Tags: web-development

I just had just started my android developing course. As soon as I complete my course how much I will be paid monthly as a freelencer.? Hoping to get reply soon. THANKS

Answer (score 5):

As a freelancer you must negotiate your own pay.

This will depend on your skill level, customer needs and financial constraints in the market you are targeting.

Comment: Please give a least a coarse range!

Comment: That is pretty much impossible as I have no idea where the OP intends to work

Comment: Guve at least the information about where know. Better to restrict than let all options open. Better to know its between 3k and 5k in a specific region than to keep wondering if its 200 all around the world

Comment: But there is no absolute number. It would be hugely different in Western Europe compared to Vietnam or similar. The best approach would be to find out what an employee doing the same work earns and multiply that by 50-100% depending on what the market allows